# Saving location to DB is wrong

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I am using java, with hibernate, saving a point object to db.
The DB is Postgresql with PostGIS

```
 DB:    location        GEOGRAPHY(POINT, 4326),

CODE:   @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,4326)")
        private Point location;
```

I am saving a point in the coordinates: -25.969130, 125.1
like so :

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(-25.969130, 125.1));
```

The save is ok, but when I load the object i get the coordinate :
x : -25.969130 y: 54.000006

But then I save the y coordinate under 89 it wont change, only higher.

Note:

If I save the y coordinate 126.1 the return value is 54.00006

And If I save the y coordinate 127.1 the return value is 53.00006

and so on and so on...

Why is it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [points](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html) int PostGIS are defined as longitude - latitude, but you are providing latitude - longitude.